# Netflix Zuul CORS

Tags: spring-boot, cors, netflix-zuul

Hello all spring boot / cloud / Netflix Zuul experts !

I am running a microservice environment using the Netflix OSS components and Spring Boot using eureka and Zuul for service discovery and routing. Multiple micro services are deployed on multiple VPS via docker. I am running an Angular JS client which accesses these microservices via a single endpoint using Zuul routing.

I am using yeoman hottowel for the angular scaffolding for the rapid development that this enables, however I am hitting a problem with CORS since the web server is running on localhost:3000 and trying to invoke a RESTful endpoint through the Zuul router running elsewhere.

I have played around with the Zuul filters (pre,route and post) to try and add the appropriate access-control headers to the response, and I can see that this works when I submit a POST request from a Rest client (I am using Paws) but when the request is submitted via angular JavaScript running in a browser, the CORS preflight OPTIONS request is not being handled by the filter, in fact Zuul returns a 403 error and the browser of course reports a CORS error.

Maybe in production I can serve the JavaScript from the Zuul endpoint and not face this problem, but I would like to know if there is a way of configuring all the CORS handling within Zuul?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? I am getting a problem from AngularJS as well with the CORS headers being doubled, which I think is happening because I have a CORS filter in my API gateway (Zuul proxy) and my resource server (service).

Comment: I was not getting any of the CORS headers returned from Zuul. Temporarily I have disabled Zuul until I figure this out. I suspect that I will just try not to be too smart and let the resource servers handle the CORS processing and Zuul proxy everything. I will update this post when I have an update. In principal I still think it a good idea to let Zuul handle CORS and authentication.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with custom cors filters. I solved this by adding the code in the zuul project as following:

```
 @Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(0);
    return bean;
}
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: where to add these bean. Please provide the detail. I am stuck in these problem from very long time

Answer (score 0):

You should add the CorsFilter inside the main class. In most cases, it should work. But if you still get the preflight CORS, try this.

Create a new class called ZuulSecurity.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ZuulSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
  }
}
```

You should be aware that Zuul Proxy requires authentication. In development, adding the code chunk above will let your API Gateway allow for preflight request and remove the authentication process to Zuul.

Answer (score -1):

I faced this issue so putting a solution here...Basically, need to add an implementation of WebMvcConfigurer.  Springboot version: 2.3.2.RELEASE, Cloud version: Hoxton.SR6... For more details, refer [this link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/pull/3278/commits/5e6dae83e1e3c9e1f73b45276b5647523ac32556)

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;


@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Value("#{'${allowedOriginList}'.split(',')}") 
private String[]allowedOriginList;

@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    log.info("adding cors config");
    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins(allowedOriginsList).allowedMethods("*").allowedHeaders( "authorization").allowCredentials(true).exposedHeaders("Cache-Control", "Content-Type");

 }  
}
```

And then define property allowedOriginList in your application.yml

```
allowedOriginList:  http://localhost:4200
```

Comment: I prefer this answer, but you forgot a little thing: The .allowedOrigins("*") call should make use of the defined property, thus: .allowedOrigins(allowOriginList). I've proposed an edit.