# Invalid CORS request for post call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

```
Request URL: ******
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 403 
Remote Address: ****
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

For the post call browser showing it as OPTIONS.

The following is the server code:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            System.out.println("onboard cors");

            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS").allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("*");
        }
    };
}
```

The above code is working fine when I directly call the respective service.

But getting 'invalid cors request' error by calling the service through zuul api gateway.

Any suggestions plz?

Comment: It's the preflight check by the browser, and to get ride of it you must implement crossorigin, I simply added `CrossOrigin` annotation in my controllers and worked. If you have  spring security in your project, the configuration you added isn't enough.

Comment: Hi Mohamed, I tried the above method but didnt work. I tried 3 ways 1. Global CORS 2. Controller level 3. Method level

Comment: The above code working but we are using zuul api gateway, by calling the post call through zuul api gateway is not working. By calling the respective service directly it is working fine.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, but i think you must have mentionned that the problem is at zuul level not the microservice itself. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Your browser first checks if POST method is safe to send to the endpoint and if yes then does POST request. You should provide permissions to OPTIONS method and respond it with `Allow: GET, HEAD, POST` and all should be okay. I faced that problem while working with Python, so it's all about CORS and does not depend on platform.

See more information about it [here](https://dev.to/effingkay/cors-preflighted-requests--options-method-3024)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me.

Add the below code in zuul project:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(0);
    return bean;
}
```

Adding corsfilter code in all microservices is not required.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46277194/4132466